# Can you solve those laser puzzles? (puzzles created by the community)

Tags: geometry, mazes, open-ended

So, I was bored and I made a small game for this site! In this game the user who solves the previous puzzle gets to create the next one and they will always be more complex. Website link and string down below!

How it works:

- You paste in the current puzzle string in the input box and press reset just to be sure. This will setup the game and place "invisible" mirrors on the board of which there are 8 types.
- You shoot lasers with a click on one of the small boxes on the side of the board the green color tells you where the laser shot came from and blue tells you where it exited. If there is only a blue box and no green box then it means that the laser entered and exited in the same box.
- You place the mirrors with first clicking on one and then clicking on a square on the board, to delete a mirror click on it again or overwrite it with another
- The 8 mirrors are:

  - Vertical and horizontal reflection mirrors (worth 1 point). As a example, let's take the horizontal mirror. If the laser comes from above or below it gets
    reflected back in the opposite direction. If it comes from left or right it passes through the mirror.
  - 45° degree mirrors (worth 3 points). I think this is pretty self explanatory as to what happens.
  - Rotating vertical and horizontal mirrors (worth 5 points). These behave the same way as their standard counterparts with the added ability that when they get hit they turn into their opposite. So if the laser comes from above at a horizontal rotating mirror it gets bounced back up and the mirror now becomes a vertical one, which then again turns into a horizontal one if it gets hit again etc etc. The rotation occurs also if the laser passes through.
  - Rotating 45° degree mirrors (worth 7 points). These are the same as the standard 45° mirrors with the rotation ability
- Your goal in this game is to figure out at which position what mirror is under. You got some things to help you with this:

  - The first is the point counter which shows what the total sum of points of all mirrors on the board, so if there is only 8 avaliable points
    and you are sure that there is one rotating 45° mirror somewhere, then that only leaves 1 point left for one basic mirror.
  - The second is the number of trys, this is a counter which tells you how many times you send a laser through from any position since innitializing the board
  - And the last thing is a counter which tells you how many squares the laser has traveled in the current shot.
- The reset button resets the board to its initial state, this doesnt delete the mirrors you placed on the board but just puts the "invisible" mirrors back in their starting position

Some additional things to consider:

- The outer layer of the board can't have mirrors in them
- You need to find out the initial state of the board so if there is only one rotating mirror on the board and you hit it once with the laser the correct solution will still be to place the initial position of the rotating mirror on the board.

When you get the correct solution to the puzzle a message will inform you of your victory and then you will be able to create the next puzzle
where you will be able to place a total points of mirror worth $n+2$, where $n$ is the previous puzzle's maximum points. The first puzzle posted by me will have
3 maximum points, so the next will have 5, then 7 etc (Scoring is now different in the new version). To create a new puzzle you simply place mirrors on the board. When you place exactly $n+2$ points worth of mirrors you get the next puzzle string. When you are creating a new puzzle you will also be able to see the actual laser traveling, and if the laser travels over a box multiple times the color will get darker.

You should also probably sort this thread after date to see the latest puzzle. The next valid puzzle in the chain will be earliest one with the correct solution to the previous one. The last thing I want to impose is the correct format of a valid answer. Edit: check out the current answers!

**Version 1** (use this version for level 1 to level 4): https://preview.c9.io/vajura/blackbox/ver1/index.html

**Version 2** (use this for level 5 and on, in this version mirrors cost more and the difficulty only increments for 1 point as a bonus the puzzle strings are 100 times smaller) https://preview.c9.io/vajura/blackbox/ver2/index.html

**Level 5 is not yet updated so if you want to solve it use Version 1, if you solve Level 5 in the old version before Josh update his puzzle to the new version you are free to create the Level 6 puzzle from this link(just start placing mirrors the points will update and when you placed a total worth of 13 the new puzzle string will be shown) https://preview.c9.io/vajura/blackbox/ver2.1/index.html**

Level 1, made by OP

```
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
```

Level 2, made by BmyGuest

```
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
```

Level 3, made by Crispy

```
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
```

Level 4, made by tttppp

```
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
```

Level 4.5, puzzle made by COTO (but originally numbered "level 4" by accident)

```
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
```

Level 5, puzzle made by Josh

```
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
```

As I know many people here are smart and I have not really spent any time on making this secure. I don't doubt that someone will decode the puzzle strings or crack the whole thing if they want too.

Also sorry for any bugs!

**BONUS: Crack the code used! *Achieved***

Comment: As for bugs: The **Reset** button does not work for me. I have to reload the page from the url to get it to reset.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it changes every answer. It's unsuitable for this site.

Comment: Suggestion; Edit the new puzzle into the question.

Comment: What do you mean edit the new puzzle into the question? Should i update my question everytime a new level of the puzzle is made? Also the reset button works fine for me, it doesnt actualy reset the pieces you put on the board but the "invisible" ones just get put back into the innitial state if they are rotating ones. Also a lot of such questions are on the codegolf & programing puzzle boards where the answers are chains

Comment: @warspyking, re "it changes every answer", if I understand correctly that depends on whether the new code replaces the old code in the question each round. Personally, I like this setup very much, it's innovative and teamworky. I suggest that the question contain all the codes for each round up to the present time, e.g. "Round 1: ABC / Round 2: DEF / Round 3: GHI". That way the question gradually expands but there's nothing to prevent someone new to it from starting at Round 1.

Comment: Edited qn as per previous comment, so the puzzle *expands* over time rather than completely changing for every round. OP, feel free to reject this edit if you don't like the change.

Comment: I don't mind the edit, but maybe we should be consistent on round vs. level.

Comment: @Crispy, right. 'Level' it is.

Comment: Can I post a question challenging people to crack this code? XD

Comment: @warspyking yea sure but i dont think it will be a hard challenge for experienced people :D

Comment: Lol I was kidding, not that it wouldn't be interesting to see what comes out of it. I got an idea :O

Comment: I've got as far as working out that the level strings are base64 encoded and are 1200 bytes which is 3 bytes per square but after that I have no idea. The programmer part of me rebels at the idea of the inefficiency of all that data!

Comment: OH you want to crack the strings directly that might be immposible because i used a hashing alghorithm with a password. I though this was more meant on back engineering the source code and finding the key and the functions there not actualy cracking the strings by hand

Comment: @Vajura: I don't know what other people want to do but I see a base64 encoded string and I get curious as to what is in it. I came to the conclusion after seeing such a big variation in the bytes for very minor variation in the input that it was probably using some kind of encryption techniques.

Comment: Yea trying to decypher that without the passphrase and the actual alghorithm is more or less impossible.

Comment: I was going to ask how on Earth you managed to stretch 16 bytes' worth of data into 1.2 KB, but it appears others have beaten me to it. :P

Comment: Well its not really 16 bytes in that string all the mirrors of the board are saved(and also empty spaces) and the current point counter so thats 401 numbers. I was lazy and didnt spend much time on it but now that thought about it i could make the string 3x smaller without much effort lol

Comment: @Vajura If you need help with re-opening the question don't hesitate to call(@) me.

Comment: I've edited out the [tag:community-generated] tag, as per the guidelines in [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). As we currently lack site policy on these tags, we'll be sticking to this for the interim.

Comment: The links are dead.

Comment: https://preview.c9.io/vajura/blackbox/ver2.1/index.html should be working

Comment: All links are dead

Comment: @Vajura That's also dead. Still.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the people who want to crack it by using code (and to get my bonus points):

> The OP used Tea crypt with the password "vaj123":

so

> `s2 = Tea.decrypt(inputS, "vaj123");` decrypts the string (in inputS) into a map of values which it saves in s2. The first value has to be discarded, the rest of the values are used to make up a 20 by 20 grid.
>  -1 is nothing placed, and 0-7 are the diffirent mirrors used.
>  You can execute the above command in the browser's console on the Black Box page.

And if you want the reverse-engineerd stuff:

> Full code of the generation of the puzzle can be found here: http://jsbin.com/civuvetezi/1/watch?js,output

Yes I know, I am a party pooper.

Good luck!

Comment: yea as i said the code wasnt really protected lol

Comment: I know. But you asked for reverse-engineering for the bonus points... So... I did that :(

Comment: Nah that request was made by another user and added to my post by them i didnt really care that much about it so i left it there

Comment: That was me :D don't worry, you get your bonus.

Comment: Just wait 23 hours for +100

Comment: @Vaj This should be accepted, it essentially solved all possible configurations.

Comment: Bonus awarded. GJ!

Comment: @warspyking I have to admit tho, it doesn't really solve anything in it's current state. Somebody still has to write a tool for it. And as soon as Vajura changes the password, this method breaks (and you'd have to reverse engineer the password again). But thanks for the bonus reward :D

Comment: @Rik_S No problem.

Answer (score 3):

Nice puzzle. The first level is easy.

**Previous puzzle** (solved below)

```
rn3VJa3YMDO55uue6CYbeRe1furuO4K/h11E3ucxaEG5IpWwOMxBEvJWw+xXz5yiyS/Oyvqvg/q3MXsT4abL2oMRF+7mJHqWJHSSpUL7Eyl+CyFP6jy0IF6u6LpW2ZGsOcsQXMOKeUBHKpImQmZM2742Y1s2VfWcboVdZ7bBuMTrtRKNwAsCV0RwaSOFm17ayPmhL1sNkT6QR7RmL2KygC6BULJmzalk6ZgOx9sS4WunLHGpk3gnQzE8qNyzvGsQck/dlIzBp/vAm2pncE6Q/ZLUmNgqDd+fxTiNFg/gx861mwNPAK6QyMmH90Ut+AHUgMx234c5FHKTVXVPbqK55zgPzmPhOYBN4K8WVqeH9BC/DOnfQTPtDe+oBb8zSSJi7iBaoZd7IG7hpVlsfGd5hHEq5bQTIrooAYlCv8AS4/gc42nQRQcB2gBKGLKbx8SrYCGwNNv99oR23sE0th8YBlSckhDobAbAcVY9b9aRfvKkTuhkJV7ShM3yxX7gn9mtjhuqVvqYpKZAjkCLPvNZhh6UAisiLbRODethmM+INL5mLgsIv6ZXkzkEfOFmh2R6m13SlesPJW8NTi+J4M6/XpR4Wl+sTDqv/2+mFqaPTRNvv/D339fqGHmtO1g1OUmT09Le7nC+88+pKX5n9CuXLrp737mNeHXszaIVm8ZpeCAJeTndkC7NE6OXqYoDxDfFBl7BRtIwCp8QXgiOEXrAiYlDpN+xKZ7J6UN+w9Z+wnc0946CNt3f27VEUWKA1hDvpk+cIqf+Kcy3rbZJlZeed2Bei4BbCeLSytsA6hcV/XKlHcHS23dAg3mRaIFxn/RYkF570vgzWY3dm6er0wkr2sK3Wd1MTYBqXL9WFhqPafZhQG97EpAI1RzXJo8Mu2TzuC5Hhx1LpMCn+9TAmLOST1oFvaJiNL+/3WPfhjm1SudooJkecf8DPy7M6K8UZvxHeYEG0jsT1JeZxTCVrSQ0FXqvb79mO+zctwFkHlOqVnGaKh6e5J8CkNQHHBVqySD/a7X5cBb5rzlxkjFPfTr6krKtHQr4KZ4CRwHMDKLqDhqFci5E0QQoQ411GuxUZ3xb5iixWaWLRFHwtT0BrCvyScKrriD/Sy4ZlIEodjz1Xt5zbBF08WnqBuY8w+246QnK6xgSdLt33VeyoZFPYtYENbqAV2CYC3C3RARO4LJfgClwTlFJhNhCealEGskre9v3n6Twm288tGhmwiLlDrGew9kKT/yXmox1jV8rkpKduXbGjPd2n7do3gALzldhmiDK0QPIIK2e//DlhgP/v5jtk38ozvuADsDSa9PLcGT2Ro+osZNwR/Sz63kwuUjPy4LG2JUcFxyTncqvpkyn1jtf1QnXxOhefRp0bYlVqx+QAQg0PSOncXGxR8UfuGFXrqFKVcKNRF1zboiicFk11A1qV3dNm4jR8YBBcmlxSXfkxI5ekxcSio+UwM4cyDmh2KcjwhzWl5zILSvu1sOhOAK+8A9LvAueWXqseCTUoTNfPqgONdGhGAzkuM9Z3Pr46DQ9LQCCDRowJ/93H8sGU1Kdyi/EcT8AdAcSzh6wUMDjpGneQcJmVlz9J6EYXNpdg+Nf
```

Current (Next) puzzle (**Level 2**)

```
C44IiCsMjgi606BiGkKKXd7O0ZFVNjAAamkCekOlNdQxtgzT1hS7HN0lby8Or+ZB9otEplgYGmENnUfwwVuAqUTD/VnygVesX7K9zGDFZphqwHw8Ji/r1KuKYLeIrxDHO54aOG880XX9LO4FSAPXxCC/azcx8zSfpg+ei5b2N4TIhLzerp8eaPgGwi0n0zQiSjm/m6ou2d5g+E4+1Jtanaz4/2p3h9eSp7bNcKg2aH0sPRxqOeQFzHqSmgQH5nzj8UFkGghqAAAeNbn2buJQDaWh4yyVVfks66wTEOD4D2xQnVikuGgFvwJ6Icgo2TEGuHq6LU3+67cFFuOcBLioQupZj9pHI8toYbD9/vdzTODEoihC9Yb0DGO94CSht2Gj18Z0v25jsmHBZ5bus999/Haz/RyyrRPK+dwUcadnZUeCVzVdZ3CLbGWmO7N2aQydTwBPlPYtXc3HrqXbp8Z0wbzHplcR6Z8e+U7Cb0qH7O++v5JMQOq8UNcqn+JUXRL3bMwPVC1V1HWh7xkgTvoOTgabTiCcBJNXJ3584SqK2NhYPlG+S5XT3MwJ1y1W52P5qSLkEpztjH1nO9XKp7P3RA3I9gIOkw6i7G3gHxtwbQsncmBFzmVswVU++wa55Ve3X0dfD2kjMUCvw22iifmuf7STzwkLIq1li0dpJo11jeEetz24QuCY5GA1FA0VqIbxfWynX060vsyIYVB0TGyd1TNwuPWzTmjbi/7F0yaY8CSG9fGBzVSz+jV4PktafHCiB4Ske/EtttzLPIL3F+2/O9nN7M+nVZa3kMvEGii8JqxxkXpGEfIEShUxzMnWCnU7CxnQgp0W3ReffQy3wAgJh7MJ+j5b5PjvAczcEJuxBRaGtrHYXzzzhAE/oL9CyOVvONyrApqYbnPl2m5QwZ8dE+HQjQVeMaDuzsTbU9QACu4Ard9ytfULZRjWWRKXgSbuR54xKhHd1t4la6b5xXoYFaaHmtUM+ZaY6OqrbMQp44EjFYTaMFZRV6+sAYx6Wmo4mfLPJquBn0OdURzxJTKb7cMvy7Q2GbxigjZmpowZ2H8rH2SfaMBTtb+osERkOqbIaKb17tlt9wA2TcI2MWLuYe8JhBx6265P6hGgNAzR2pFzYJTuo+wbKAJwYLhkp19rCaoMwy/YtitfaYuBavf+jCZ5DeJ+wfpgDGANBMVWWiobxYdlqH0z+7YWMTC5S9PzEqnQ1IqcjU5k+yZTAMNH0JYWZ8A9u20+gtm3G6ye6m/2DezwafNp4pgYT1nd1v/u6gjBfOZvk4KjTU2JppJQfGwVfRn5KXOYZb7KbR5kKtm9sg2TaTYKwJiuOyqXP9SaYh57mCk+5ALJKMKaII1m2sfWZFiSrs/7q3TTWdKoZu8PFSbN3z07Mw3DhFdtg6eM/eeyUoFj0LoL/X4/5E25ry4rSE3YoT6V+HPFM2lEXv3/G+/Q/17yYs1DZbGg/w5AyMI8xPg9EpWLJgocyRvjWN69ydnGnkVsnr3HLPuSsJ1Noeoa/Pj9xDmhURHHH0h7xY5M5z7H55B8QTZ1ZHh/dDkyvh/erz8wQ8kgsyZux5M04NtcmpFOdPXYQ+Eix2SO
```

Level 1 Map

> [image: Solution1]

Comment: dont really understand what you mean there. Yes you need to go through every spot there is no other way really. Also you can post the next puzzle now

Comment: @vajura I got the "solved" message, but I did not get a new string? What I meant is, that if I want to get the best "score" (least tries) I can restart the puzzle once I've solved it and use only the remembered (needed) lasers.

Comment: When you solve the puzzle YOU create a new puzzle you can remove the previous pieces(or leave them) and place new ones so that in the current situation you can place mirrors on the board which would be worth a total of 5 points (lets say 5 horizontal mirrors) then the new puzzle string appears. You post this string here and let other people then try to solve your puzzle and then when they solve it then THEY can again create a new puzzle with even more mirrors. Check out the format on how you should be posting answers

Comment: @Vajura Got it now. Will edit in a sec.

Comment: Looking at this am I right in thinking that the rightmost mirror could have been placed anywhere on that line to the right and still been a valid solution?

Comment: @Chris: Yes, I was wondering that myself. ...and then was too lazy to test it. Go ahead and try!

Comment: Well it doesn't tell me that it is the right solution but I can't see how it couldn't be. Anything vertical in that column is unaffected and the direct reflection of the horizontal can happen at any distance...

Comment: @Chris There's a Distance value.  So the Distance value tells you where to place the right most mirror.

Comment: @Crispy: ah yes. I had failed to notice that.

Comment: Distance is a also a good key to help determine if one of the switches is used.

Answer (score 3):

**Previous puzzle Level 3** (solved below)

```
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
```

Current (Next) puzzle (**Level 4**)

```
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
```

Level 3 Map

> [image]

Comment: Yup. You done broke it.

Comment: @COTO Retesting now it seems very broken! Oops.

Comment: @COTO Hopefully fixed now - thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3):

## Current Level (4)

An automatic +1 from me if you can figure out what the heck is going on here:

```
u0S6f3vkLrci2hA9fY4sPEZkMfdZsq7/cjNoy0wL3S7utpfX8rsX6B6/GYBxMtn6GuSBXXQIUCsnOrYze7KGtxgS0ywnQlptbvqfryNGYDep0LFk/Ij/iRTocU3GwEME82Z0RA7cC5KH1d/wNM7jMWPC7wqjNk44u+oziAra+FMIDkFwKjtVNIFBnEKACHB0z4gKzcgSmtFV6ziXjzk51Ukvfjc4g1bFapNIWvos6q1ARkkw44nNuxXUnmus/QB8jhN32SiuyhQkzYBiNO02TBTS+B43M7zJHL95iFgTuF326VLkA79QMwKbpfEONv/xFeL3+Ck3jDvc2YjtknOv7aDGc2kgcsQkmiXEOBcVzkQjQDCKEa4p+z+ZHhHJy83uOEu8Iwnp7+h427pvXGZn9UYZv2gl0V0MxYTwx6OLv3rZf/3Whdrv29uGtjOy01z537QuRk0XXytECq2zOfmO6JD7NaJZTM2VL9qshizSmQ/b//yWugJl2Ojadsxc43BvNaSAi6gyIwJudYP8FyaZru2Lst9tvGEyf7jyN/UkMpOmqYfU4fsXMCiE9w1WHULjnpx5vgRhx4Kdf+3Zm0k6smoqY/l4uxGf3rhHddWjTuy+UX+42gsEyc/ynQ/STfVXfeQfVAFcwexWZmDy/dhP42rjSBEYZymbAKkEnOXlkuXQvSn5N0kb51c4kzUVFA0+tLsSqh+j7K/zYkUuul+L/K8FT/f6CvQA2yK8Ah1a5bTRNUYgwBe2Slz6tPMpASeXaXsyq42PVH3XpVReVsqvNgk6HpJTCDUmzl5P/qMicEOcj2yyTsM9Mgm1xTGr8bTpW+I7+63jADlT9gyzNZ2/Lq+oCS06h05DhG7llTo9pkjj+4ovhMjigY/Z8vDKWLlHnY1uUYK2DmdgLHz05DykEdEtXfgG0BN16VEHxbBf4eXcAzRQ1KzfsmR9Tbb8JguelrtSht+lODLuuwhMimzsJ2dRTOfhX3gwNhMZ+JR4c3eXoLpy7QBfHoCkGTl2cVBgZNjB0fZPmJp4mkuuZnUCcz+0d9WRZNTRSfnPQSpr2m5j5v//3IXDi4AwHox5PSFUaTsLBUw/+p+rC7lDlxpPycWz6kzgub5nhqKISUCHckvZGo6aSMmwS9VgDMMLh7GhSjDnY+T1Bb8izrij6dJvnbcye4OcfcptTyVPiE3j0Pr3hwhV8YHBIqQgtOfc53ciyh1OS3QfPehr5BxVSyuViXjfYBad3eTAqiHd7FaLnCCNUjsTj3ZZHhxK1okR3uheFVfyg6EHi33ifRNRngg41E0YzC8gk7WywuBkNaebbtiqNfF85RK6hL8vQli39RItm/vniU6wJTzdlxO9uPcvyQGsPlBLqG8iBAVc9bd521uYnIP2QdaPe57MX9lJJwYn9A0GHZF2o84eeAnfHRx7YYfk8PtFRka+pF+32dAI89UERIvrR4KKHcq7HaV4IG7pqHghi056glHT3uZU52Fqoq2tos1iKe3V3kDaNZk0Q+fz+Ib99zlp07+0opn5oFJkvoPVtonZVViK+q62SSkj/cx6DDaH293GXEmidAu5kBv6LNYjEXTqXsci8I0vwXap
```

---

### Previous Level (3) Solution

The solution is posted below.

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

That was fun!

**Previous puzzle Level 4** (solved below)

```
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
```

Current (Next) puzzle (**Level 5**) (Remember to user version 2.1 to solve - https://preview.c9.io/vajura/blackbox/ver2.1/index.html)

```
rqwgvscLaVzBZqUhhlWFfM7I2GtsUHrIHlcDkE9ARxA=
```

Level 4 Map

> [image: solution to 4]

Good luck! I tried not to obfuscate the internals too much ;)

Comment: Hello would you mind redoing your level if i increase the point count on the rotating mirrors so that the puzzles wont get really hard really fast?

Comment: Use this link to setup your new puzzle https://preview.c9.io/vajura/blackbox/ver2.1/index.html

Comment: done :) This one is a lil easier than the first version

Answer (score 2):

**Previous puzzle Level 2** (solved below)

```
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
```

Current (Next) puzzle (**Level 3**)

```
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
```

Level 2 Map

> ![image]

Comment: nice one took me more time then i excpected

Comment: I figured we better use one of the switches soon for practice/understanding before things get too complicated.  Personally I think the puzzles may get really difficult with the switch and trying to determine which switch was use to start the puzzle.  It'd probably be better to have 2 switch options instead of 4.  Clicking on the laser switches the switches and after several laser's have been triggers, it becomes difficult to determine what the starting position of the switch was without starting over.

Comment: i think making the 3 point mirrors cost 6 points and the rotating 2 point mirrors cost 4 while also decreasing the difficulty increase by 1 point could be good. Maybe even limit the number of rotating mirrors and adding a counter to see how many of them are on the board could provide enough insight