# Coppers - Make 24

Tags: formation-of-numbers, cops-and-robbers

The make-24 puzzle is an oldie, but a very fun one at that.

> Given four different numbers, produce—through a sequence of operations upon only those four numbers—the number twenty-four.

For example, given $2,2,3,8$ you can make $24$ by: $2\times 3\times\frac82$.

Note that each of the given numbers must be used exactly one time each in the solution, and no other digits may appear anywhere.

---

Here cops can submit puzzles for [the robbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50261/robbers-make-24) to solve!

As a cop, your job is to create a specific make-24 problem. You must specify:

- The four numbers a robber is allowed to use to solve your problem
- and the operations they are allowed to use (note that it's implied by default an answer should use a finite number of operations.)

For example, a good cop post may look like:

> I remember being set this kind of challenge in school, one of them was quite tricky. I'll just give you the same problem our teacher gave us:
>
> Make $24$ using $2,2,2$ and $1$ and any of the operations: multiplication, addition, subtraction, unary negation, division, factorial, square rooting, and modulus.
>
> I managed to solve it with three of those operations, maybe you can beat me!

---

Somewhat-important questions raised in comments:

> For the example, is the goal is to get 24 out of 2, 2, 2, 1 using 3 operations tops? An answer with 4 operations is not valid.

Actually, the cop is not allowed to limit the number of operations. However, unless the cop states otherwise, you should assume that the number of operations you use must be finite.

Comment: @theonlygusti I have a feeling that its moving in a direction of [tag:semi-interactive-puzzle]

Comment: Why does someone think this is a bad question? Please, rather than silently downvoting you can help me, I'm extremely new to this community.

Comment: @theonlygusti Upvoted it. But, if you see the tag wiki, semi-interactive/interactive kind of puzzles are not much liked by the community. Though, personally, I liked it.

Comment: @Techidiot hmm, hadn't heard of that. Looks kinda similar, but this is more a dumping ground for lots of different similar puzzles, rather than a single progressing puzzle. Also, it's funny to me that the tag is no longer meant to be used, but the only two tagged as such are greatly upvoted.

Comment: The more normal procedure would be for any given make-24 problem to be submitted as a question, and answers to those problems to be submitted as answers to the corresponding questions. It's not clear to me what advantage the more indirect approach here has. I suppose it clutters up the most-recent-questions less.

Comment: I've closed this as too broad because there are too many possible answers. Puzzles and questions should have a limited number of correct answers; this does not.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I'm also a huge fan of number-formation problems like these, but feel that they're often too trivial/short to be given an entire question of their own.

Comment: @Deusovi If this is being closed, you should probably do something to the corresponding "robbers" question too...

Comment: @Deusovi I feel that that's a false premise upon which to close a question on this site, I can think of many (well-received) questions here which have infinitely-many correct solutions. I feel too that judging this significantly different type of question by the criteria used to judge the regular questions here won't work. But you're much more experienced than me on this site, so I'll pretend to take your word for it.

Comment: I feel like this may be a discussion for the [meta](http://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'd argue that those questions should be closed, too. But even if they *were* acceptable, this doesn't even *have* any valid answers! It's just asking *other* people to make puzzles, which [already](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6066/can-you-solve-those-laser-puzzles-puzzles-created-by-the-community) has [precedent](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25325/cops-the-ultimate-compass-challenge) as being banned.

Comment: @F1Krazy The second link in Deusovi's comment is to an earlier meta discussion of "cops&robbers" questions. There's no suggestion there that they're *necessarily* too broad, but there is an acknowledgement that that's an easy trap to fall into.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Fair enough. I can certainly see why these types of questions might be considered "too broad".

Comment: This seems like a great way to collect basic-variation puzzles and their solutions in just two posts total! Probably should be more clearly explained, though, as its unfamiliarity is likely to trigger a lot of allergic responses around here.

Comment: Yeah. Personally, I don't think this is a bad style of question. I think it would have been extremely fun to allow the community to challenge each other with similarly narrowly-scoped problems. Some people are allergic to fun.

Comment: Stop with the downvotes, it's been settled: this is going to be closed, there's no need whatsoever to continue putting down a newbie who tried to come up with a fun first challenge for the community.

Answer (score 2):

[I hope I'm understanding the intended procedure correctly: an *answer* here is meant to be a *question*, to be *answered* by an *answer* to the "robbers" question. Right?]

My personal favourite 24-puzzle sounds very simple but is surprisingly tricky: *make 24 from the numbers 3,3,8,8, using only arithmetic operations*.

Comment: Yeah, you understood the task perfectly! And that looks like a very interesting problem...

Comment: Jolly good. You suggested an edit that removes my initial comment in square brackets; I'm afraid I'm going to reject that edit because I think it's helpful to be more explicit about what's going on here. The "cops and robbers" format is a bit unusual.

Comment: If this proves popular then once there are a few separate "cops" posts I will remove the bracketed comment.

Comment: Ok, sure :) I know that the cops and robbers format is quite popular on other SE sites, but there's only a couple posts here.

Comment: @theonlygusti Am I suppose to put the solution to this [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50261/robbers-make-24/50263#50263) ?

Comment: @Techidiot Nope. Go to the "robbers" thread and post a solution that links back here.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Done and solved :-)

Comment: ah good, then I can post the solution to theonlygusti's.

Comment: ... except that you already did. I didn't want to solve his before mine was done because, as you saw, they use the same idea.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan It's done as well. Was a similar one.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the only solution I know for this one is extremely surprising as it really forces you to think outside of the box.

Use $1,3,4,6$ and any of the arithmetic operators to make $24$. Trust me, the solution I've seen is really beautiful :)