# Robbers - Make 24

Tags: formation-of-numbers, cops-and-robbers

The make-24 puzzle is an oldie, but a very fun one at that.

> Given four different numbers, produce—through a sequence of operations upon only those four numbers—the number twenty-four.

For example, given $2,2,3,8$ you can make $24$ by: $2\times 3\times\frac82$.

Note that each of the given numbers must be used exactly one time in the solution, and no other digits may appear anywhere.

---

This question is for the robbers to submit solutions to the problems posed by the cops.

The [cops' thread](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50259/coppers-make-24) should contain posts which specify the

- four numbers you are allowed to use
- operations you are allowed to use

Have a look at the problems people have submitted [on the cops' thread](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50259/coppers-make-24) and see if you can solve any of them. If you do manage to solve any, show it off here!

Make sure that your answer contains a link back to the problem's post, you can get the url by clicking the "share" link at the bottom of an answer.

[image: share a link to this answer]

So, your answers should be somewhat modelled like:

> I had a lot of fun solving Chris' problem! Here's his post: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/404. I can use plus, minus, divide, multiplication, square roots and factorials to get $24$ from $3,8,12,50$ and I finally did it!
>
> And my solution:
>
> > $$\sqrt{50\times8}+\frac{12}3=24$$

Answer (score 2):

Answer to [Gareth's Clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50262/30887)

> $8/(3-8/3) = 24$

I hope this is how it's done.

Comment: Wow... that's awesome xD

Answer (score 2):

Answer to [theonlygusti 's Clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50264/30887)

> $6/(1-3/4) = 24$

I hope this is how it's done.

---

Edit by Rosie F (Rather than posting a comment, I edit the answer, so that I can hide the spoiler)

There is also the solution

> $1^3*4*6$

Comment: Aww... you used the same technique for both XD Maybe give others a chance ;) But yeah, this is how it's done, hope it'll take off now that we have a few examples!